# Windows Phone: PositionChanged not firing Windows 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, location, windows-phone-8.1

I am having a problem with windows phone, I am seeting up a geolocator position changed event, I instantiate and set up the GEOLOCATOR  as follows:

```
 geolocator = new Geolocator();
 geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
 geolocator.MovementThreshold = 100; // The units are meters.
 geolocator.PositionChanged += geolocator_PositionChanged;
```

And I have the positionchanged event as below:

```
void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            marker = (UserLocationMarker)this.FindName("UserLocationMarker");
            if (marker != null)
            {
                marker.GeoCoordinate = args.Position.Coordinate.ToGeoCoordinate();

            }

        });
    }
```

When I fire this up in an emulator, the PositionChanged properly gets fired 1 time, with the last location entered into the location in the TOOLS function... but any subsequent GEOPOINTS I add to the location tool never fire the positionchanged method.... I don't think its the emulator itself as if I start maps on the emulator and use the location tool it properly will change the user location with every update.  But in my code, I put a debug on the positionchanged method and it is ONLY called the first time when the app starts and that's it... once its gotten the geolocation onte time, that's all she wrote.. never fires for any action over in the location tool.

Nothing in my code destroys the geolocator object... yet no other inputs ever trigger it... I am at a loss.. any help on what I am missing or not understanding would be appreciated.  At this point I am wondering if the UserLocationMarker from the toolkit is somehow destroying or removing the position change event listener registration or something.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this reference to correctly respond to Position Changed Events:  [MSDN PositionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465142.aspx)

Make sure you declare the Geolocator on the UI thread.  I tested the following code out on my Windows Phone 8.  I walked around the office and watched the button's content change based on where I was in the building.

It could be that your MovementThreshold is too high or the emulator is acting up.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{    
    Geolocator geo = null;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        geo = new Geolocator();
        try
        {
            geo.MovementThreshold = 1.0;
            geo.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
            geo.ReportInterval = 2000;
            geo.PositionChanged += geo_PositionChanged;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private void geo_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // my_button is just a normal button on the main xaml page
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            this.my_button.Content = e.Position.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString() + "\n" + e.Position.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check [How to test apps that use location data for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202933(v=vs.105).aspx) to get more knowledge on how to test your app that use location services.

And for your info, this question already got an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382134/geolocator-position-changed-event). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me, works good and similar to HERE Maps app:

```
geolocator = new Geolocator();
geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
geolocator.ReportInterval = 2000;
geolocator.PositionChanged += geolocator_PositionChanged;
```

Doesn't matter how much metters you go away from the last position caught, after 2secs, the app will catch your current position again
Try to test the app on a real device